# GroupBox visibility

Tags: c#, winforms, groupbox

I've working on an app that displays a restaurant menu and the user has to select which items he wants. I'm using group boxes instead of multiple forms for each of the different categories of food and drink. However some of the group boxes are not becoming visible even after I set their visibility to true. Any help on this issue please?

The main form has the following code:

```
    private void drinksButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        drinkGroupBox.Visible = true;
    }
```

The designer has this code:

```
    this.userGroupBox.Controls.Add(this.drinksButton);
```

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: code posted. When I debug the code, the visibility is always remaining false.

Comment: We might need a bit more code in order to diagnose the problem. Is the `drinkGoupBox` behind another control?

Comment: Use View + Document Outline and verify that you didn't accidentally put the groupbox inside of another one that isn't visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private void drinksButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    drinkGroupBox.Visible = true;
    drinkGroupBox.BringToFront();
}
```

Would be interesting to see where it says

```
...Controls.Add(this.userGroupBox);
```